# ejabberd muc/sub default configuration

Tags: ejabberd, stanza

Is it possible to automatically add MUC/SUB subscription for every new member that join a MUC room.

For example

1. urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages
2. urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:affiliations
3. urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:subject
4. urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:config

Which is similar to running the following iq :

```
<iq type='set'
    from='hag66@shakespeare.example'
    to='coven@muc.shakespeare.example'
    id='E6E10350-76CF-40C6-B91B-1EA08C332FC7'>
  <subscribe xmlns='urn:xmpp:mucsub:0' nick='mynick'>
    <event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages'/>
    <event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:affiliations'/>
    <event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:subject'/>
    <event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:config'/>
  </subscribe>
</iq>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible yet with current code.

Comment: Hi Mickaël, can you suggest any alternatives on how can I automate the MUC/SUB?

Comment: You have to read ejabberd MUC modules and patch it to behave like you want it to work.